# How to Check Username Availability with AJAX / jQuery Validator in Wordpress?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, wordpress

I've been trying to get this to work, but the code I'm using is not using the Wordpress AJAX functions correctly. The jQuery keeps trying to access the wrong url for admin ajax. I'm also not sure if my PHP code is correct or not because it seems like there's no code to deal with an empty input:

PHP:

```
//Ajax Password Checker
function load_user_checker() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/js/user-check.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl
}
add_action('init', 'load_user_checker');

function ajax_action_checker() {
    //Validation
    $username = trim($_POST['user_login']); 
    $username = mysqli_escape_string($username);

    if ( username_exists( $username ) ){
        echo 'false';
    } else {
        echo 'true';
    }
    die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_ajax_action', 'ajax_action_checker' ); // ajax for not logged in users
```

JS / jQuery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#formid').validate({        
      rules: {
        user_login: {
          required: true,     
          remote: {
              type: 'post',
              data:
                    {
                        'action': 'ajax_action',
                        'user_login': function()
                        {
                            return $('#formid :input[name="user_login"]').val();
                        }
                    }
            }           
        }       
      },
       messages:{
           user_login:{
           required: "Please enter a username.",
           remote: jQuery.validator.format("{0} is already taken. Please choose another username")
           }            
      }
  });
});
```

Thanks for your help!